# deselect radio button

Tags: user-interface, radio-button, tkinter, python-2.6

I am working under Windows 7, Python 2.6 , Tkinter.

I need help to deselect the radio button in the GUI each time a user selects one. I have three radio buttons in the same group, and a reset button. When a user selects the reset button, all the radio buttons need to be deselected.

This is the declaration of the radio button:

```
self.Rb1 = Radiobutton (self.parent, text = 'Is this a required pre_action to the next step?', variable = self.var, value = 1)                
self.Rb1.place (x = 100, y= 400)
```

and the button "Reset" that binded to the command OnReset:

```
def OnReset(self):
    self.v1.set("Organ")
    self.v2.set("Instrument")
    self.v3.set("Surgical Action")
    self.Rb1.deselect()
```

But the `.deselect()` method does not erase the black bullet from this widget! It selects all of the radio buttons (where I have 3 radio button in the GUI). Please help me to understand how I can fix this.

I tried to destroy the radiobutton and declare it again with the same configuration values but is destroyed and appeared again with a black bullet (i.e. selected).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I just tested and found out that if you set the value of `variable` to a value that doesn't correspond to the `value` argument of any of the radiobuttons, the buttons appear with none selected. So if your three radiobuttons set `self.var` to 0, 1, and 2, respectively, you can make it so that no option is selected with `self.var.set(3)`. Since 3 does not correspond to any of the radiobuttons, none of the radiobuttons will be selected.

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Radiobuttons are designed so that one in a set should always be selected. This behavior is what users expect. Radiobuttons by definition means "exactly one choice from this set". In your specific case, the buttons mean either "yes" or "no", so there is no third choice. Boolean values can only be one of two choices. There's no harm in going ahead and picking one for the user as a default (unless, perhaps, you are writing software for a nuclear reactor or a medical device). If you deselect all, the default is wrong 100% of the time. If you pick either of the two values you'll at least guess right half the time.

In general, if you really want the user to be able to select none of the choices, add an additional option that is "unknown".